# Using ObjectWriter. Gives me EOF Exception even though I close the file.

Tags: java

/*This program serializes the students.
 *If the file exists, then the program loads it.
 *Otherwise it makes a new class list. 
 *Student objects are added to the class list then saved
 */
It is part of an assignment, however I've never used objectWriter before.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.EOFException;

public class ClassList{

 public static void find(int sN, String fN, String lN){
    boolean found = false;

    try{
    ObjectOutputStream objectOS = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("ClassList.data"));
        ObjectInputStream objectIS = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("ClassList.data"));
        int i=0;
        Assignment readAssign = (Assignment) objectIS.readObject();
    Student studentRead = readAssign.getStudents().get(i);

        /*Search the student objects & compare student number.
         *If found, boolean returns true, else the boolean is false
         */ 
        while (readAssign.getStudents() != null){
             studentRead = readAssign.getStudents().get(i);
             if (studentRead.getID() == sN){
                  found = true;
                  break;
             }
             i++;
        }

        /*If the boolean found is true error message is produced
         *If the boolean found is false then it adds a new Student object
         */
        if (found = true){
             System.out.println("A student with this id number already exists by the name:");
             System.out.print(studentRead.getFName() + " " + studentRead.getLName());
         objectOS.flush();
     objectOS.close();
        }
        else{
             Student student = new Student();
             student.setFName(fN);
             student.setLName(lN);
             student.setID(sN);
             Assignment assign = new Assignment();
     List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
     students.add(student);
     assign.setStudents(students);
             System.out.println("Done");
             objectOS.writeObject(assign);
         objectOS.flush();
     objectOS.close();


        }

    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnf){
     cnf.printStackTrace();
}
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnf){
     fnf.printStackTrace();
}
catch(EOFException of) {
     eof.printStackTrace();
}
    catch(IOException ioe) {
     //ioe.printStackTrace();
}

 }



  public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner stuIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Use student Input to create students
        System.out.println("What is your first name: ");
        String fName = stuIn.nextLine();

        System.out.println("What is your last name: ");
        String lName = stuIn.nextLine();

        System.out.println("What is your student number: ");
        int sNum = stuIn.nextInt();

        find(sNum, fName, lName);

 }


}
```

Error Message:

java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2601)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1319)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at ClassList.find(ClassList.java:28)
    at ClassList.main(ClassList.java:100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

```
ObjectOutputStream objectOS = new ObjectOutputStream(new 
    FileOutputStream("ClassList.data"));
```

... overwrites the existing file with an empty file. You then try to read an object from that empty file.

You should read first, *then* open the file for output.

I'd actually break this code into separate methods:

- Read assignment (open, read, close)
- Process assignment (no IO)
- Write assignment (open, writem, close)

Also note that:

```
if (found = true)
```

doesn't do what you want it to. It will *assign* to `found`, and then *always* execute the body of the `if` block. You want:

```
if (found == true)
```

or better yet

```
if (found)
```